# Avoid duplicated content in slightly different DataTemplate

Tags: uwp, winui-3, winui

I have the datatemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemWithCanvas"
              x:DataType="itemVM">
    <Canvas>
           <Grid x:Name="common">
               ...
           </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now, I want a similar datatemplate but no Canvas, instead of duplicating the code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemWithNoCanvas"
              x:DataType="itemVM">
           <Grid x:Name="common">
               ...
           </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

What should I do to avoid duplicating as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CommonContent" x:DataType="local:ItemVM">
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind FirstName}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind LastName}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemWithCanvas" x:DataType="local:ItemVM">
            <Canvas>
                <ContentControl x:Name="Common" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CommonContent}" />
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemWithoutCanvas" x:DataType="local:ItemVM">
            <ContentControl x:Name="Common" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CommonContent}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsRepeater ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemWithoutCanvas}" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}" />
        <ItemsRepeater ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemWithCanvas}" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```